# Ubuntu 19.10 avoid pasting carriage return in terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, copy-and-paste

I've found a couple posts about this with older versions of ubuntu & terminal. I am interested in a safeguard when pasting terminal commands similar to iTerm on macos, which warns when pasting a command that includes a carriage return. Is such behavior possible on any terminal running on ubuntu? The older posts seem to suggest only pasting into an editor and removing the carriage return, prior to pasting in terminal.

Comment: Possibly interested in zsh but for the time being assume that I am trying to arrive at a solution without switching from bash.

Answer (score 1):

You could paste it into a "Here Document" (in `man $SHELL`):

```
cat <<"UnmatchedString"

<paste here>

UnmatchedString
```

2 caveats: "UnmatchedString" cannot be at the beginning of any pasted line, and "UnmatchedString" MUST be quoted to stop shell interpretation.

Or, you could read the command carefully before you paste it.

Comment: Kudos to read command carefully. No objection to restating that!